# Spring boot: Two FactoryBean<RestTemplate> implementations

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've just created a `FactoryBean` implementation in order to request `RestTemplate`:

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateFactory
    implements FactoryBean<RestTemplate>, InitializingBean {

    //init resttemplate headers
}
```

So, now I'm able to inject a `RestTemplate` at whichever class:

```
@Service
public class DocumentServiceBackOffice {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public DocumentServiceBackOffice(RestTemplate restTemplate) {//...}

}
```

However, I'd like to create another `FactoryBean<RestTemplate>` in order to initialize other parameters.

How could I create in order to inject one or other according to a `qualifier`?

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateFactory
    implements FactoryBean<RestTemplate>, InitializingBean {

        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

        private JWTService jwtService;

        public RestTemplateFactory(JWTService jwtService) {
            this.jwtService = jwtService;
        }

        public RestTemplate getObject() {
            return this.restTemplate;
        }

        public Class<RestTemplate> getObjectType() {
            return RestTemplate.class;
        }

        public boolean isSingleton() {
            return true;
        }

        public void afterPropertiesSet() {
            this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            JWTHeaderRequestInterceptor jwtInterceptor = new JWTHeaderRequestInterceptor(this.jwtService);

            this.restTemplate.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(jwtInterceptor));
        }

}
```

Comment: Use `@Qualifier`... Also I would suggest not to use a `FactoryBean` but just inject the `RestTemplateBuilder` in an `@Bean` method instead.

Comment: Where should I use `@Qualifier`? On `FactoryBean` implementations?

Comment: The constructor argument.

Comment: I think you mean `DocumentServiceBackOffice(@Qualifier RestTemplate restTemplate)`. But, I don't quite figure out how this `@Qualifier` is associated to an `FactoryBean<>` or another...

Comment: Use the name of the bean.

Comment: Could you provide an short minimal helping code on an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `FactoryBean` just use an `@Bean` annotated method which accepts a [`RestTemplateBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html) and use that to configure instances.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate fooRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, JWTService jwtService) {
    return builder.additionalInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new JwtHeaderInterceptor(jwtService)).build();
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate barRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder {
    return builder.build();
}
```

This will result in 2 available `RestTemplate` instances. The `fooRestTemplate` (marked as default due to `@Primary`) and `barRestTemplate`. To specify the specific one to use add an `@Qualifier("barRestTemplate")` to use the not default one.

```
public DocumentServiceBackOffice(@Qualifier("barRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) { ... }
```

Comment: Is there any more elegant way to "qualify" constructor parameter? I mean without write literal string...

Comment: What about singleton?

Comment: You can create your own qualifier annotations (I suggest a read of the Spring Reference guide which explains all of that). I don't get your singleton comment.

Comment: In my `FactoryBean.isSingleton` returns `true`. How could I get that injected rest templates are singletons?

Comment: That is the default for `@Bean` methods... I strongly suggest a read of the Spring and Spring Boot reference guide as all those questions are answered in there.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be defining a configuration with two `RestTemplate` beans with *qualifiers*.

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("firstRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate firstRestTemplate(){
        // any building logic here
        return new Resttemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("secondRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate secondRestTemplate(){
        // any building logic here 
        return new Resttemplate();
    }

}
```

Then, in your code, use the right `@Qualifier` when autowiring.

**Setter injection example:**

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("firstRestTemplate")
    private RestTemplate template;

    // ...

}
```

**Constructor injection example:**

```
@Service
public class Service {

    private RestTemplate template;

    public Service(@Autowired @Qualifier("firstRestTemplate") RestTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    // ...

}
```